# Calling javascript with python subprocess

Tags: javascript, python, subprocess

This is actually working. But I just want to make sure.
Can you please tell me if I am doing right? or I just need to use some python interpreter package?

```
exec_code = f"my code calling the function to append to temp file"
file = 'js/test.js'
temp = f'{file}_temp.js'
with open(temp, 'w') as f:
    with open(file, 'r') as origin:
        f.write(origin.read() + exec_code)

js_ctx = ['node', temp]
res = subprocess.run(js_ctx, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip('\n')
print(eval(res))
```

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: It really depends on the JavaScript you want to be running. The way you're doing it now means that the script is running on node.js on your computer, which could be extremely unsafe if the javascript you receive can be manipulated by others. If you just want something to run in a browser, you could instead use something like a Selenium web driver, or cross-compile into Python using Js2Py (for limited use cases) or run the code in a separate engine using PyV8 - just as a few examples. The current solution also means it only works on computers that have node.js, of course

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply and suggestion.
This is actually for personal use. I always have nodejs installed. But I'm gonna try js2py.

Comment: @Grismar I tried js2py but i don't understand how to run the file and execute the function and give the params to the function

Comment: That's probably a good separate new question to post, provide an example of what you have in a .js file, share the Python code you wrote with js2py and explain what the problem is you run into.